# Сохранение изменений в ячейках JTable при применении разных редакторов

Tags: java, swing, jtable

В приведенном коде к ячейкам таблицы применен разный JFormattedTextField, проблема в том, что при изменении значений в ячейках они не сохраняются, подскажите как можно решить данную задачу? Код приведен целиком

```
public class KadrPress extends JFrame{
    public KadrPress() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Кадровая работа");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(lineMenu(),"North");
        this.add(osnTabPane(),"Center");
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    //Создание меню
    private JMenuBar lineMenu()
    {
        //Меню файл
        JMenuBar lineMenu=new JMenuBar();
        //Меню Файл
        JMenu filemenu=new JMenu("Файл");
        JMenuItem newFile=new JMenuItem("Создать");
        JMenuItem openFile=new JMenuItem("Открыть");
        JMenuItem saveFile=new JMenuItem("Сохранить");
        filemenu.add(newFile);
        filemenu.add(openFile);
        filemenu.add(saveFile);
        filemenu.addSeparator();
        filemenu.add(new ExitAction());
        lineMenu.add(filemenu);
        return lineMenu;
    }
    //Создание основной панели с вкладками
    private JTabbedPane osnTabPane()
    {
        JTabbedPane osnTabPane=new JTabbedPane();
        osnTabPane.addTab("Общие сведения",osnovSvedeniyaJLabel());
        osnTabPane.addTab("Лист 2",new JPanel());
        return osnTabPane;
    }
    //Панель основные сведения
    private JPanel osnovSvedeniyaJLabel()
    {
        JPanel osnovSvedeniyaJLabel=new JPanel();
        osnovSvedeniyaJLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        osnovSvedeniyaJLabel.add(levayaJTable());
        osnovSvedeniyaJLabel.add(new JLabel("2"));
        return osnovSvedeniyaJLabel;
    }
    //Модель основной таблицы
    private JTable levayaJTable ()
    {
        String[]dannie=new String[]{
                "Фамилия","Имя","Отчество","Личный номер","Число, месяц, год рождения",
                "Место рождения (согласно паспорта)","Серия и номер паспорта","Дата выдачи","Кем выдан",
                "Код подразделения","Серия и номер удост. личности (Военного билета)","Дата выдачи(ВБ)",
                "Кем выдано","ИНН"
        };
        JTable levayaJTable=new JTable(new OsnovTable(dannie));
        levayaJTable.setRowHeight(20);
        levayaJTable.setOpaque(false);
        levayaJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                .setCellEditor(new MaskEditor(new JFormattedTextField()));

        return levayaJTable;
    }
    //Модель основной таблицы
    private class OsnovTable extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        String[]dannie;
        HashMap<String,String>data=new HashMap<>();
        public OsnovTable(String[]dannie) {
            this.dannie=dannie;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dannie.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==0)return dannie[rowIndex];
            if (columnIndex==1) return data.get(dannie[rowIndex]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==0)return false;
            if (columnIndex==1)return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.put(dannie[rowIndex], (String) aValue);
        }
    }

    //Создание редактора таблицы
    private class MaskEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    {
        public MaskEditor(JTextField textField) {
            super(textField);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            JFormattedTextField result= (JFormattedTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            MaskFormatter dateMask;
                try
                {
                    if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Число, месяц, год рождения")
                            ||table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Дата выдачи"))
                    {
                        dateMask=new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");
                    result=new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
                    }
                    if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Серия и номер паспорта"))
                    {
                        dateMask=new MaskFormatter("#### ######");
                        result=new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
                    }
                    result.setBorder(new LineBorder(null,0));
                    return result;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return result;
        }
    }




    //Команда выхода из приложения
    class ExitAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public ExitAction() {
            putValue(NAME,"Выход");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KadrPress();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему то у ячеек с редактором не вызывает метод setvalueAt модели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частично решил задачу новым редактором. Но теперь не могу выйти нажатием ввода из редактируемой ячейки, но эта проблема меньше

```
private class MaskEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    private JFormattedTextField editor;
    private JTable jtable;

    public MaskEditor() {
        // создаем форматирующий объект
        JFormattedTextField editor = new JFormattedTextField();
        editor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stopCellEditing();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                     boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        MaskFormatter dateMask = null;
        try {
            if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)
                    .equals("Число, месяц, год рождения")
                    || table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)
                    .equals("Дата выдачи")) {
                dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");

            } else if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)
                    .equals("Серия и номер паспорта")) {
                dateMask = new MaskFormatter("#### ######");
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        editor = new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
        editor.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editor.getText();
    }
}
```